# Luong Attention and Bahdanau. When should we use Luong or Bahdanau?

Tags: machine-translation, attention-model

i'm kind new with machine learning concept, especially machine translation. I've read about the Luong's Attention and Bahdanau's Attention. Luong is said to be “multiplicative” while Bahdanau is “additive”. But i still don't know which one is better and when we should use Luong or Bahdanau

[image: luong]

Comment: thks for your advice :)

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr**: Luong's attention is faster to compute, but makes strong assumptions about the encoder and decoder states. Their performance is similar and probably task-dependent. However, the mainstream toolkits ([Marian](https://github.com/marian-nmt/marian), [OpenNMT](https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT), [Nematus](https://github.com/EdinburghNLP/nematus), [Neural Monkey](https://github.com/ufal/neuralmonkey)) use the Bahdanau's version.

**more details**: The computing of the attention score can be seen as computing similarity of the decoder state **h<sub>t</sub>** with all encoder states **h<sub>s</sub>**. If you assume the vectors come from the same vector space, you can simply measure their similarity using a dot product. If you assume there exists a linear correspondence between the encoder and decoder states, you can use the *general* variant with single matrix multiplication.

These assumptions probably do not hold, or at least there is no good reason why they should be in general. However, they make the attention computationally simpler than the standard Bahdanau's attention, here denoted as *concat*. Bahdanau's attention is, in fact, a single hidden layer network and thus is able to deal with non-linear relation between the encoder and decoder states.

Comment: i think h(t) should be current decoder state and h(s) is source hidden states. In the [Minh-Thang Luong paper] (aclweb.org/anthology/D15-1166), he said that the alignment vector a(t) is derived by the comparing the current target hidden state h(t) with each source hidden state h(s). Does he means that h(s) was a vector create by concatenation from multiple hidden states from encoder ?

Comment: You are right, I swapped the indices. Yes, __h<sub>s</sub>__ is a concatenation of the forward and backward runs of the encoder.